# Why installers made with Installforge/InnoSetup are showing false positive?

Tags: inno-setup, antivirus, false-positive, install-forge

I made an application in python and converted it to exe using Pyinstaller which is tested clean.
I tried making an installer for the exe using both installforge and inno setup but it shows a false positive message for B!ml type virus like Wacatac and Bearfoos.

Is there any easy fix or alternative to remove these false positives?

Comment: You can sign the installer as Martin says. Alternatively, upload your installer to VirusTotal, see who reports, and report to individual vendors as false positives. (Unfortunately this is due to the fact that bad actors use legitimate tools.)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Unfortunately, its not signed. Have to look for some cheap certificates.